# GRASS convert raster to points

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have tried to convert a raster to points using this syntax (`r.to.vect`):

```
r.to.vect input=g_kelowna_merged@kelowna_mapset output=g_kelowna_points feature=point
```

I have tried using the GRASS interface in QGIS and also directly in GRASS GUI 6.4.3 and 6.4.4.

What happens is that the points get created and show in the **Map name** box but there is nothing in the **Layer** box and QGIS says "No layers available in this map". Looks like I created a map, not a layer. Any suggestions for getting those points?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why your `r.to.vect` is not working as expected in QGIS. Maybe your raster is too big? When I am running it from processing toolbox and choose *Save to file* it creates as expected point shapefile and loads it into map under temporary layer name.

For big rasters you can try convert raster into points (x,y,z) in QGIS by using **Raster / Conversion / Translate** and choose output format as **ASCII grided XYZ** which generates text file of x,y,z. That is definitely way more robust and faster method. It is very handy when you need to do something with XYZ in non-GIS software. You can easily load it into QGIS as points through **Add Delimited Text Layer**.

(In GRASS also `r.out.xyz`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe youneed to define a region from your input raster.
I had the same problem and the cause was the region

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that the process took so long to run that I thought it had quit. This time I  cut the raster in half and then created a smaller raster using r.thin and let it run. Still it produced 600,000 points. I'll try it again, using a raster that is even more thinned.